# ERROR 500 al enviar formulario php

Tags: php, html5

me esta quemando la cabeza!!! cuando doy enviar a un formulario php me aparece "ERROR 500" en lugar de enviarlo....
Comparto el código para ver si alguien encuentra lo que yo no :(

codigo html:

```
<div id="contact_form">
  <form action="contact.php" id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <div id="closeForm" onClick="displayFormContact('none')"></div>
      <figure id="logo_mensaje"></figure>
      <p>Como puedo ayudarte?</p>

      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Tu nombre">
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Tu email">
      <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="1" placeholder="Escribe aqui tu mensaje"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="buttonEnviar" value="ENVIAR">
  </form>
</div>
```

php (nombre: contact.php) ubicado en la misma carpeta que el index.html:

```
<?php
   $para = 'fer.elaskar@outlook.com, graficaelpunto@outlook.com';

   $asunto = "mensaje de la web de el punto!!!!!!!!!!!!";

   $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
   $mailheader .= "Reaply-To:".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
   $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

   $MESSAGE_BODY = "Nombre: ".$_POST["name"]."\n";
   $MESSAGE_BODY .= "\n<br>Email: ".$_POST["email"]."\n";
   $MESSAGE_BODY .= "\n<br>Mensaje: ".n12br($_POST["message"])."\n";

   mail($para, $asunto, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die("error al enviar mensaje, intente nuevamente")
   header("Location: http://graficaelpunto.com/web")
?>
```

Si quieren ver lo que sucede la web es

graficaelpunto.com/web

Muchas gracias por sus aportes

Comment: `"Reaply-To:"` -> `"Reply-To:"`  , `n12br` -> `nl2br` : New Line 2 (to) (line) BReak

Comment: El error 500 ocurre cuando algo anda mal en el servidor. Me parece que se debe a esto: `n12br`. La función se llama **`nl2br`** (tienes un `1`, y debe ser una `l`, una letra *ele*. También, deberías escribir un código más elegante, usando variables para no escribir tanto `POST` y escribir todo uniforme: o  `\n` o `<br>` o mejor todavía si usaras `PHP_EOL`

Comment: Puedes tomarle una foto a la pantalla del error y subirla aca?

Answer (score 1):

El error 500 ocurre cuando algo anda mal en el servidor. Me parece que se debe a esto: <s>`n12br`</s>. La función se llama [**`nl2br`**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.nl2br.php) (tienes un 1, y debe ser una l, una letra ele).

También, deberías escribir un código más elegante, usando variables para no escribir tanto POST y escribir todo uniforme: o `\n` o `<br>` o mejor todavía si usaras `PHP_EOL`.

Vamos a corregir el error y a mejorar el código:

```
<?php
   /*Capturamos las variables del POST con operadores ternarios*/
   $email=   ( empty($_POST["email"])   )  ?  NULL : $_POST["email"];
   $name=    ( empty($_POST["name"])    )  ?  NULL : $_POST["name"];
   $message= ( empty($_POST["message"]) )  ?  NULL : $_POST["message"];
   /*Verificamos que los tres datos fueron posteados*/
   if ($email && $name && $message){
       $para = 'fer.elaskar@outlook.com, graficaelpunto@outlook.com';
       $asunto = "mensaje de la web de el punto!!!!!!!!!!!!";
       $mailheader = "From: ".$email."\r\n";
       $mailheader .= "Reaply-To:".$email."\r\n";
       $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

       $MESSAGE_BODY = "Nombre: ".$name."\n";
       $MESSAGE_BODY .= "\n<br>Email: ".$email."\n";
       $MESSAGE_BODY .= "\n<br>Mensaje: ".nl2br($message)."\n";

       mail($para, $asunto, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die("error al enviar mensaje, intente nuevamente");
       header("Location: http://graficaelpunto.com/web");

   }else{
        //Aquí puedes también redirigir con un mensaje de error
        echo "Error, no se postearon los datos necesarios";
  }
?>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por las correcciones (estoy empezando y en un curso daban este código para formularios). Reemplace el codigo de mi archivo con el codigo que me pasas (copiando y pegando para evitar errores de tipeo) y sigue el error... alguna otra solución por favor

Comment: @Fernanda faltaba también el `;` al final de las líneas donde tienes las funciones `mail` y `header` (las dos últimas antes del `else`).